# what are the uses of the session in asp.net explain with real example.how to declare the session

Tags: asp.net-web-api

what are the uses of the session in asp.net explain with real example.how to create the session and how to use it.How session should be maintained through out of the page.i am creating one session variable in my application,always it is showing the null value only.

Comment: Check out [**Exploring session in Asp.Net**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net). It has everything you need to learn.

Comment: Besides, StackOerflow is for programming related QA. Please avoid asking such questions. Here is a tour on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A simple browser search will furnish you with plenty of information on this.